# Zend 2: How to configure errors with custom controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

My question is regarding customizing how errors are handled in Zend 2.

Suppose I'd like to customize the layout such that I want to do this in an action in my controller:

```php
$layout = $this->layout();
$myNav = new ViewModel(array('nav' => $this->getNav());
$myNav->setTemplate('layout/nav');
$layout->addChild($myNav, 'navigation');
```

Works great when I place this into my controller for regular (i.e. non-404) viewing. Now I've customized my layout so that I can do `<?php echo $this->navigation; ?>` and the `layout/nav.phtml` is fired up and everything works just hunky dory.

Now, suppose I want to do the exact same thing when errors are rendered. I need to be able to inject the above code somehow prior to the error handler returning it's own `ViewModel(...)` into the `error/404.phtml` template.

How do you do that?

I suspect that it's something like setting up the correct class for the service manager like this in `module.config.php`:

```php
'service_manager' => array(
    'services' => array(
        'error_handler' => 'MyModule\Controller\MyCustomErrorController'
        //and so on...
```

How do I do this?

UPDATE:

In my `Module.php` I've attached a method for `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR`. Variant A works, Variant B does not. So you can't use partials here?? Am I missing something really basic??

**Variant A**

```php
public function onDispatchError(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $sm  = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $vm = $event->getViewModel();
    $vm->setVariable('nav', '<h1>test do i work?</h1>');
    //Works
}
```

**Variant B**

```php
public function onDispatchError(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $sm  = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $vm = $event->getViewModel();
    $nav = new ViewModel(array('test'=>'hello there'));
    $nav->setTemplate('layout/simpletest');//contents: <?php echo $this->test; ?>
    $vm->addChild($nav, 'nav');
    //In the template, <?php echo $this->nav; ?> has nothing...
}
```

Comment: After 6 years, is there still no simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Zf2 use module.config.php file to set error handling:

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
```

This should handle 4xx client errors and 5xx server errors.

For custom error page in specific module.

```
namespace ModuleName;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module implements
    BootstrapListenerInterface,
    AutoloaderProviderInterface,
    ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadConfiguration' ), 100);
    }

    public function loadConfiguration(MvcEvent $e)
    {
    $sm  = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $controller = $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller');
        if (0 !== strpos($controller, __NAMESPACE__, 0)) {
            //if not this module
            return;
        }

        //if this module
    $exceptionstrategy = $sm->get('ViewManager')->getExceptionStrategy();
    $exceptionstrategy->setExceptionTemplate('error/errorcustom');
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig(){ /* common code */ }
    public function getConfig(){ /* common code */}
}
```

The solution is provided by "samsonasik" from http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/zend-framework-2-create-custom-error-page/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this doesn't allow me to customize the layout by injecting layout variables (such as `$layout->addChild(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to an even to handle what happend when a 404 is triggered:

Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    /**
     * Log any Uncaught Errors
     */
    $sharedManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', 'dispatch.error',
         function($e) use ($sm) {
            /**
             * Decide what to do now we've got a problem...
             * Log the issue etc..
             * You could forward to some custom controller if you wanted..
             */
            //$sm->get('Zend\Log\Logger')->crit('an error occurred... bla');
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            //$routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
            $controller->layout('somelayout'); // possibly change the layout..
         }
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm guessing that since this is an error, `$e->getRouteMatch()` doesn't exist since there was no valid route match which led us to this `dispatch.error` event in the first place.

Comment: that was just some example code in there not tested, just to give an idea what you can access, it's down to you to decide what you need to do :)

Comment: I'm all good with example code :) I just meant that I'm not sure I understand why `$e->getRouteMatch()` would return anything in the case where no route was found.

Comment: it wouldn't it was just5 some example stuff pasted in there from another example of Event usage, that wasn't really the relevant part though the point is you can use events to do what you need :)